# Scientific explanation for extreme fighting strength

Tags: science-based, technology, martial-arts

I was wondering if there is a scientific way to explain how my characters are capable of extreme levels of strength when engaging in combat.

My characters are biological but have implants that allow them to create energy attacks, such as electricity, lasers, plasma and chemical attacks of poison, using gas and a spark for fire as well as other attacks yet to be designed.

I contemplated giving them metal or nano material bodies to give them extreme strength but I would prefer to keep them as biological as possible but with a lot of help from individual implants.

Is there a scientific explanation for extreme strength using implants but in the form of a strong force when needed, maybe by means of creating an energy field or something similar, that is activated the moment they strike or are struck?

My story in general is near future technology but I don't mind certain aspects being more in the realm of science fiction.

Edit. to clarify i am talking about a repelling force from their fists and feet when they attack to hit the opponent harder and a force like a shield for defence which could be the same repelling force.

Comment: You are mixing up terms. Force, energy and fields have well defined scientific meanings, which do not match up with anime-esque martial fighting. I don't see how you can give a science based answer, since if you interpret the terms scientifically, it is glibberish

Comment: un called for saying its gibberish, i think its quite obvious i don't have the scientific knowledge that is why i am asking the question, it is answerable to someone that understands the question.

Comment: I'll point out that not all muscles are built the same. For instance, a male chimpanzee is 1/2 to 2/3 the size of a human male, but roughly the same strength, and a male gorilla is roughly the same weight as a male human but can be four to ten times stronger. I do not know the biological reasons behind this, but I'm sure you can dig up some research on it, and then invent some chemical or biological system for increasing a human's physical power.

Comment: @TedWrigley thanks, i have read questions on here about the muscles fibres in apes, its a good idea and i could play around with biochemistry for juiced up strength , for this i was looking for silly strength well out of biological possibilities, i thought some physics could create an external force for the push.

Comment: @ChrisW Hit a person and send them flying 50m or more.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://www.hackster.io/Advanced/punch-activated-arm-flamethrowers-real-firebending-95bb80

Comment: "as biological as possible" Is there any reason this would exclude carbon fiber reinforced bone & tendons to make the organism much tougher? Putting something like the avian lung system in would allow higher persistent power output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Concept: Exoskeleton and Prosthetics**

I believe that we can derive inspiration from powered exoskeleton suits. Development for them have been started as early as the 1910s, and by the 1960s, linked from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powered_exoskeleton#History):

> the first true 'mobile machines' integrated with human movements began to appear. A suit called Hardiman was co-developed by General Electric and the US Armed Forces. The suit was powered by hydraulics and electricity and amplified the wearer's strength by a factor of 25, so that lifting 110 kilograms (240 lb) would feel like lifting 4.5 kilograms (10 lb). A feature called force feedback enabled the wearer to feel the forces and objects being manipulated.

Although the Hardiman weighed 1500lbs, and was too clunky for actual use, modern day suits such as the Lifesuit prototype 14 'can walk 1.6 km (1 mi) on a full charge and lift 92 kg (203 lb) for the wearer', making them much stronger.

Assuming more futuristic technology, we could use the Exoskeleton suit technology and apply them to implants. Arms and legs can be replaced with prosthetics based on Exoskeleton technology, reinforced with materials, and coated with skin-like substances (similar to a terminator). The prosthetics would make the user more durable, allowing them to withstand the impact of their own enhanced strength, as well as stronger, with some actuators inside the prosthetics. The user can further enhance their strength using a powered exoskeleton suit, linking their prosthetics to it for enhanced strength, durability, and stamina. The prosthetics themselves can be powered with something like a nuclear isomear battery to provide lots of energy capacity with small volume, referenced from this answer [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95803/what-is-the-best-idea-for-an-advanced-type-of-battery-for-my-future-sci-fi-world).

As to releasing electrical shocks, shooting fire, etc. these can all be add-ons to the prosthetics. You could have a flamethrower add-on with a fuel canister, igniter, and pump added to a prosthetic.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to borrow shamelessly from the excellent web serial *[DeathWorlders](https://deathworlders.com/)*, and the Dresden Files, by Jim Butcher, in my answer:

## Healing

Newton's 3rd law says that if your enhanced soldiers can throw a punch that knocks an adult male 50m, they're getting thrown 50m the other direction.  (And the adult male will be *dead*, because that much force delivered over the surface area of a human fist in a single impact is going to make a hole.)

So you need the soldiers to be bigger.  If you're going to make them bigger, you may as well add a ton of muscle.  And the way that you can accomplish all of that (within certain limits, probably) is to come up with a device or compound that supercharges healing, and makes it *perfect*.

Rather than scar tissue, the tissues affected by this implant *heal*.  The supersoldiers thus equipped can exercise longer and harder than unaugmented humans, do damage to joints, rip muscles, and even break bones... and then they can do it again the next day.  And the next.  Combine that with a carefully-calibrated nutrition program and you're going to have soldiers who leave olympians and champion weightlifters in the dust.  They'll hurt themselves every time they fight, but the implant will help with that too.

Answer (score 2):

An implant that could deliver a sudden electrical shock to the nerves that control the relative muscles would enable someone to achieve strength greater then an average human. However, this will cause the muscles to tear much quicker. This will result in a period of time when recovery is needed - but the user will be much stronger afterwards.

Combined with a material that can resist the tearing more efficiently - you would have a person that is incredibly strong.

Answer (score 2):

They could have implants in the heart that injects a minimal amount of adrenaline or other hormones that could dramatically increase the strength though it would be very dangerous to use this, is the minimal aproach. They could have also implants in the brain that inhibit pain to achieve this.

Compressed air can be used to create an explosion let's say in the hand they can create a little crystal balloon with compressed air they slap the enemy and the balloon explodes.

An augmented articulation let's say the hip. A punch's strength is the accumulated strength of all the body if you increase the power of one part of that chain you increase the outcome.

Genetic alteration, they have been genetic altered to have a a superhuman capabilities of course using this abilities all the time hurts them permanently. So the solution to this is adding a trigger. This trigger could be stress or even a keyword. If they have'nt been "triggered" they have the normal capabilites of a human.

Bear in mind that all this options would also harm the user.

Brutal training, i mean the kind of training that kills. Over the history there has been humans that were considered monsters inside of our kind. They achived their level of skill and strenght thru training that almost killed them. You can also notice the Shaolin monks in this category. That combined with some minor augmentation could produce really superhuman combatants.

Some know cases of people like this are:

- Bruce Lee
- Masutatsu Oyama
- Morihei Ueshiba
- Jigoro Kano

Answer (score 0):

#### Accomplishment in Energy

Through long years of dedicated training of energy martial arts, your human beings have increased their natural energy to the highest potential. This perfectly describes their supernatural physical strength, endurance and energy attacks.

Besides the physical body, all human beings posses an energy body made out of energy, which is closely associated to bio-electricity. Your warriors have been taught through martial arts how to develop their energy and unlock their hidden potential. This allowed them to have super-human capabilities.